# Given $a_{n+1} = \frac{{a_n}}{\sin({a_n})}$ with $0 < a_1 < \frac{\pi}{2}$. Show that the limit $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}{a_n}$ exists and find it.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

Given $0 < a_1 < \frac{\pi}{2}$, for $n\geq 1$ we define
$$a_{n+1} = \dfrac{{a_n}}{\sin({a_n})}.$$
I need to show that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}{a_n} = L$, and then I need to find $L$.

I can't find a way to bound $\{a_n\}_n$ so that  $$0 <a_n < \frac{\pi}{2}$$ I've tried to use every convergence test I know, but I always have the same problem which I want to bound $\{a_n\}_n$ and can't to that without bounding $\{\sin(a_n)\}_n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that for $x\in (0,\pi/2)$,
$$x<f(x):=\frac{x}{\sin(x)}<\frac{\pi}{2}.$$
The left inequality is trivial while the one on the right is equivalent to $2x/\pi<\sin(x)$ which holds because $\sin(x)$ is concave in $(0,\pi/2)$.

Therefore, since $a_{n+1}=f(a_n)$ and $a_1\in (0,\pi/2)$, it follows that the sequence $(a_n)$ is strictly increasing and bounded above by $\pi/2$.

This shows that the limit $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}{a_n}$ exists. Are you able to find it?

Comment: i bounded {${a_n}$} from below by zero, which was no problem, but i'm still struggling to bound it from above.

Comment: $\sin(x)$ is concave in $(0,\pi/2)$ so it stays above the secant $y=2x/\pi$ (the line through $(0,0)$ and $(\pi/2,1)$).

Comment: Numerically, it "seems to go" to $\displaystyle\color{red}{\pi/2}$.

Comment: \begin{align}
&\texttt{Clear[i, x]; x = N[(Pi/2) RandomReal[]];
For[i = 0, i < 10000, ++i, x = 1/Sinc[x]];}
\\ &\
\texttt{N[x/(Pi/2)]}
\end{align}
yields $\color{red}{0.999919}$.

Comment: Yes, the limit $L$ is $\pi/2$. It is the unique solution of the equation $L/\sin(L)=L$ in $(0,\pi/2]$.